# Using jquery, key board short cuts to do not fire in input controls

Tags: jquery, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have to use key board short cuts in web application using jquery. And i am able to do that so. But when i am using the same characters for short cuts are firing even when they are in input control.

For example: When clicked on a, it will redirect to home page. but when same a is pressed in any input control, then also it is re-directing.

Answer (score 0):

You could stop the `keyup` event on the input from bubbling up with something like this:

```
$("input[type=text]").on('keyup', function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try disable them on $.focus event for every input area.

For example:

```
 $('input[type="text"], select, textarea').focus(function(){
        $.keyboardShortcuts('unbind');
    }).blur(function(){
        $.keyboardShortcuts('bind');
    });
```

$.keyboardShortcuts is just a generic name I gave to your keyboard shortcuts plugin.
Make sure to have a bind/unbind function in your plugin, or just create it.